# why is direct access to an array not possible using a magic __set() method?

Tags: php, oop

Ok, so here's a snippet of my `Properties` base class, that is extended in most of the classes in my application:

```
class Properties {
    protected $properties_arr = array();

    /**
     * Magic function to be able to access the object's properties
     * @param string $property
     */
    public function __get( $property ) {
        if ( array_key_exists( $property, $this->properties_arr ) ) {
            return $this->properties_arr[ $property ];
        }

        return $this->getUndefinedProperty( $property );
    }

    /**
     * Magic function to be able to access the object's properties
     * @param string $property
     * @param mixed $value
     */
    public function __set( $property, $value ) {
        if ( property_exists( $this, $property ) ) {
            $this->setProtectedProperty( $property );
        }

        $this->properties_arr[ $property ] = $value;
    }
```

It's pretty basic, and there's nothing wrong with it, but I'm running into a problem that I've encountered a couple times before, and it's that you can't perform certain actions on an `array` property through the __get method.

Doing this, for instance:

```
$MyClass = new Properties();
$MyClass->test = array();
$MyClass->test['key'] = 'value';
```

you would expect the `$MyClass->test` array to contain one item, but it's still an empty array! Now I know I can work around it by just assigning an array with the items already in it, but I would just really like to know why this is (and if there's a better solution).

Thanks!

Comment: What is `Properties::setProtectedProperty($var)`?

Comment: Just an internal method that throws an `Exception`, but can be overridden by a child class to customize the behavior. Do you think this could have something to do with the problem? I'm not overriding it in the class where I'm experiencing the problem.

Comment: Probably no, it should not be a problem. See @Peter's answer, it works for me. Without it, I got PHP error "*Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property Test::$foo has no effect*" (do you have error reporting enabled?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [PHP Accessor functions and arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077956/php-accessor-functions-and-arrays).

The issue is probably that you need to make the __get() method return a reference.

Comment: Yup; reckon that's it. See also [this bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=39449) for a little history. @Rijk, I think that your code should have thrown a warning on your array access -- do you have error reporting turned on?

Comment: Ah right, now I understand! I already found this solution in the PHP.net comments, but the author didn't explain it as well as in the post here on SO. The problem for me is, that this triggers a "Only variable references should be returned by reference", because of the conditional `getUndefinedProperty()` return.. :(

Comment: @Matt: I sure do, everything including Notices. It doesn't trigger a warning - could you tell me what error you were expecting?

Comment: @Rijk What version of PHP? Having chucked your code at my installation of 5.3.5, I get `Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property Properties::$test has no effect in C:\Matt\xampp\htdocs\properties.php on line 33`.

Comment: @Rijk, as for "*Notice: Only variable references should be returned by reference*", just assign result of `$this->getUndefinedProperty($property)` to a variable before returning it.

Comment: @binaryLV: smart, hadn't thought of that yet! Have any of you considered making arrays 'native' properties added from the `__set()` method to avoid this problem?

Comment: @Rijk, to be honest, I wouldn't advise to use `__set()`/`__get()` at all. Same goes for any kind of "non-native properties" - do NOT create them on the fly. Everything should be defined and documented to avoid confusions ;)

Comment: All right, very informative, thanks everyone! @binaryLV: I'll consider your advise, you have a valid point.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you need to also override the __isset magic method to check if the array index exists.

Comment: Hm, I've just implemented an `__isset()` method, and it appears to not be called at all? Is this not the one used to override `isset( $Object->property )` behavior?

Comment: It's like : public function __isset($key) { return isset($this->tab[$key]); } . I had this issue when doing nearly the same thing as you, and this solution made the trick.